# Google BigQuery Table located on Google Bigtable is not listing in Power BI

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, google-cloud-bigtable

I have created an instance on **Google BigTable** and created an *external table on **Google BigQuery*** and created an external table which can able to fetch records from BigTable.  I tried to create a BigQuery datasource in **Power BI Desktop** but the external tables are not listing but the tables created on BigQuery are been listed!  Is it an *issue*? or any possible solutions?

Comment: This seems to be related to how Power BI is getting the table information. Was the table you created a permanent or temporal table? Did the issue persist after refreshing the data from Power BI?

Comment: Hi @Tlaquetzal i have created permanent table in bigquery which used to query data from the table in bigtable.Yes the issue persist even after refreshing the data.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to create a big query view in the same dataset that points at the table, eg if your table is `your_dataset.your_external_table` you create a view that does `select * from your_dataset.your_external_table` and the view will be visible in the power bi interface.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your scenario and got the same behavior as the one you described. It seems that at the moment Power BI does not support BigTable external tables. A workaround is to create one or more views based on the BigTable table and then connect to those views.

In addition, if you're interested you can report the Power BI behavior [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/idb-p/Issues).

Comment: Hi @Tlaquetzal I Just reported the issue on the Page.